# mysqli fetch_assoc() - ошибка

Tags: php, mysqli

Не пойму в чем проблема, проверял запрос на работоспособность, он отрабатывается без проблем.

> Notice: Undefined variable: res in
>   /home/m/mukhamwf/hata.test/public_html/reg.php on line 37 Fatal error:
>   Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on null in
>   /home/m/mukhamwf/hata.test/public_html/reg.php on line 37

```
//авторизация
if(isset($_POST['auth'])){
    message::info("Вход на сайт"); 
        $view="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.email='$email' LIMIT 0,1";
    if($rez=$mysqli->query($view)) {$row = $res->fetch_assoc();};

}
```

Comment: возможно проблема в строке
$view="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.email='$email' LIMIT 0,1";
'$email' проверяетса не значение переменной а строка $email

Comment: Проблема не в этом - т.к. в ручную прописывал уже email, что-то вроде этого - $view="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.email='test@mail.ru' LIMIT 0,1";

Comment: _Undefined variable: res_ - что именно в этой фразе непонятно?

Comment: Поясните, условие возвращает true

Comment: if($reZ=$mysqli->query($view)) {$row = $reS->fetch_assoc();};

Comment: убил на это два часа, оплата за не внимательность, и не опытность,  спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка в коде. Вы присваиваете результат переменной $rez, а обращаетесь потом к $res. Вот работающий код:

```
//авторизация
if(isset($_POST['auth'])){
    message::info("Вход на сайт"); 
        $view="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_info.email='$email' LIMIT 0,1";
    if($rez=$mysqli->query($view)) {$row = $rez->fetch_assoc();};

}
```